# How to find third coordinate of triangle when two coordinates and their corresponding angles are given

Tags: geometry, coordinates, trigonometry

i am trying to calculate third coordinate of triangle ABC, where A(x1,y1) B(x2,y2) angle CAB=a1 and angle CBA=a2. i need to find third coordinate C(x3,y3)
i had thought of using law of cosines, but they may result some complex equations to solve.

i need some simple technique to solve them, or using some direct formulas or any other method that can be implemented in computer program.

can anyone help me in this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least two ways are possible:

1. Through lines

   - Build a line equation for each triangle edge containing unknown vertex
   - Find intersection of these lines
2. Through circles

   - Find length of each unknown edge using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines
   - Find intersections of two circles