# Third point in triangle with two coordinates given

Tags: geometry, coordinates, distance

I am not good with math,and i just need someone to point me in the right direction.

```
Latitude    Longitude
N 36° 13.488'   W 095° 54.295'
N 36° 13.488'   W 095° 53.805'
```

Assume that all three  are located on a flat plane, at the same elevation.
Assume that the curvature of the earth is not a factor.
Assume that there are exactly 69.1691 miles per degree of latitude.
Assume that there are 55.9588 miles per degree of longitude (Tulsa area only)..

I am trying to figure out what the last points coordinate is.

Can anyone help. I just dont know where to begin

Comment: Any three points form a triangle. The third point could be anywhere.

Comment: right, the distance between A to B is the same as the distance from A to C and B to C,    and the third point is south of the two given

Comment: At least now you know what basic math is good for, take out your math school books, or use some online resource to study the math of triangles, sin, cos, tan (for atan use atan2())

Comment: Similar question has been replied very well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861904/how-to-find-coordinates-of-a-2d-equilateral-triangle-in-c

Answer (score -2):

There are numerous ways to find the third point. The angles in an equilateral triangle are all 60 degrees. The third point lies on the bisector of the line connecting the two points you have. Expressing the points and lines using vectors, rather than coordinates, helps.

But the truth is, if you do not have enough mathematical knowledge for this kind of problem,  you probably ought not to be tackling it as a programming problem.  How can you know you've done it right?

Comment: See also   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883849/calculating-the-coordinates-of-the-third-point-of-a-triangle

Comment: See also   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966805/how-to-find-third-coordinate-of-triangle-when-two-coordinates-and-their-correspo